# Remove double quotes from a string in python

Tags: python-3.x

Would like my output which should not be string but my code returning string to me. Please look on my below code in which z is my output. I tried with regex, replace, strip, eval, ast.literal_eval but nothing worked for me as of now.

```
x = "'yyyymm'='202005','run_id'='51',drop_columns=run_id"
y = x.split(',')
print(y)
```

This will print:

```
["'yyyymm'='202005'","'run_id'='51'","drop_columns=run_id"]`
```

But I want:

```
['yyyymm'='202005','run_id'='51',drop_columns=run_id]
```

Comment: The output you want isn't valid Python.

Answer (score 0):

`x` is a string and if you split a string, you will get an array of strings. It is basically cutting it into pieces.
Your question is not really clear on what you want to achieve. If you want to have key-value-pairs, you'd need to split each token at the `=`. This would give you something like this:
`[('yyyymm', '202005'), ('run_id', '51'), ('drop_columns', 'run_id')]`
But the items in the tuples would still be strings. If you want to have integers, you would need to cast them which is only possible if the strings consist of digits. It would not be possible to cast `'run_id'` to integer.

You can refer to this example. I'm not sure if that is 100% what you are looking for, but it should give you the correct idea.

```
x = "yyyymm=202005,run_id=51,drop_columns=run_id"
y = x.split(',')

tmp = []
for e in y:
    tmp.append((e.split('=')[0], e.split('=')[1]))

out = []
for e in tmp:
    if str.isnumeric(e[1]):
        out.append((e[0], int(e[1])))
    else:
        out.append(e)

print(out)
```

This will give you:
`[('yyyymm', 202005), ('run_id', 51), ('drop_columns', 'run_id')]`